# How to insert variable into sqlite database in python?

Tags: python-3.x, sqlite

My code seems to run fine without any errors but it just creates an empty database file with nothing in it, Cant figure out what i'm doing wrong here.

```
import sqlite3 as lite
import sys
con = lite.connect('test43.db')

def create_db():
    with con:
        cur = con.cursor()
        cur.execute("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Contacts")
        cur.execute("CREATE TABLE Contacts (First Name TEXT, Last Name TEXT, Phone TEXT, Email TEXT);")
        cur.execute("INSERT INTO Contacts VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?);", (firstname, lastname, phone, email))
        cur.commit()

#Get user input
print ('Enter a new contact')
print ('')
firstname = input('Enter first name: ')
lastname = input('Enter last name: ')
phone = input('Enter phone number: ')
email = input('Enter Email address: ')

createnewdb = input('Enter 1 to create new db: ')
if createnewdb == 1:
    create_db()
else:
    sys.exit(0)
```

Comment: shouldn't it be `insert into contacts VALUES ...`?

Comment: Yea i actually corrected that part but it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not getting to the `create_db()` method, as the `if` clause is comparing a `string` to a `number`.  [`input()`](http://docs.python.org/3.2/library/functions.html?highlight=input#input) returns a string, so you really should be comparing it to another string..

try the following:

```
if createnewdb == "1":
    create_db()
else:
    sys.exit(0)
```

Then, you should call `commit()` on the [connection object](http://docs.python.org/2/library/sqlite3.html#connection-objects), not the cursor.. so change your `create_db()` method a little here too:

```
def create_db():
    with con:
        cur = con.cursor()
        cur.execute("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Contacts")
        cur.execute("CREATE TABLE Contacts (First Name TEXT, Last Name TEXT, Phone TEXT, Email TEXT);")
        cur.execute("INSERT INTO Contacts VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?);", (firstname, lastname, phone, email))

        ## call commit on the connection...
        con.commit()
```

then it should be working for you!

Comment: Works now, Thanks a lot. It's amazing how 2 very tiny mistakes caused the whole program not to work lol.

Comment: haha, such is the way with programming. One piece of advice is to put debugging lines that print things in your code.  For example just inside the function definition, put a line saying `print("create_db() function called")` and that way you know where the program is getting to when it writes its output  :)

Answer (score 3):

I found this example for inserting variables to be very helpful.

```
c.execute("SELECT * FROM {tn} WHERE {idf}={my_id}".\
        format(tn=table_name, cn=column_2, idf=id_column, my_id=some_id))
```

Here's the link to the tutorial.
http://sebastianraschka.com/Articles/2014_sqlite_in_python_tutorial.html

Answer (score 0):

The reason that your database file is becoming blank isn't because your varbiables aren't inserted into your SQL syntax properly. Its because of what you did here `cur.commit()`. You're not meant to commit your cursor to save any changes to the database. You're meant to apply this attribute to the variable in which you've connected to your database file. So in your case, it should be `con.commit()`

Hope this helps :)