# SYNTAX ERROR in python sqlite3 INSERT statement

Tags: python, sqlite

I have been writing a small program for data entry and have been very frustrated because of a simple error. I am unable to figure it out. The Query is as follows:

```
query1= """
'INSERT INTO general_demographic 
(serial_number,district,mprpmu,ward,telephone,name,age,occupation,education)
VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)',
(str(SerialNumber.get()),
str(District.get()),
str(mprmmu.get()),
str(ward.get()),
str(telephone.get()),
str(name.get()),
str(age.get()),
str(occupation.get()),
str(c.get()))
"""
```

The error displayed is shown in the figure below: 
[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5wve0.png)

Comment: Please edit your question and paste the error message as text.

Answer (score 1):

Your query is invalid but you are on the right track.

Instead of `q = "'SQL (?) ', param_tuple"` you should do more like this:

```py
q = "SQL (?)"
valz = param_tuple
cursor.execute(q, valz)
```

Actually the [documentation of parameter substitution is quite good.](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html#cursor-objects)

[There](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/228912/sqlite-parameter-substitution-problem) [are](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13880786/python-sqlite3-string-variable-in-execute) [many](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42401775/sqlite-python-how-to-use-parameters-for-select-and-union) [examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19759349/how-to-insert-variable-into-sqlite-database-in-python) [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41269140/insert-variable-in-sqlite-value) [too](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48086236/inserting-variable-stored-data-into-sqlite3-python-3).